# NSFetchRequest not fetching chat messages in proper order

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data

I am implementing a chat database using core data in iphone. I have created two entity chatuser and chatmessage. and there is one to many relationship between chatuser and chatmessgae entity. For one chatuser there can be many chatmessages. I am storing data like

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
        NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Chatuser"    
                                                  inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
        [request setEntity:entity];   

        NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"chatuser == %@", chatuser];
        [request setPredicate:pred];

        NSArray *userArray=[self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];


        if ([userArray count] > 0){
            Chatuser *user = [userArray objectAtIndex:0];

            Chatmessage *message = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Chatmessage" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
            message.chatmessage = chatmessage;

            [user addAllchatmessagesObject:message];
            NSError *error;

            if(![self.managedObjectContext save:&error])
            {
                NSLog(@"whoops, couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
            }           

        }
//    }
    else 
    {
        Chatuser *user = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Chatuser" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
        user.chatuser = chatUser;

        Chatmessage *message = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Chatmessage" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
        message.chatmessage = chatmessage;

        [user addAllchatmessagesObject:message];
        NSError *error;

        if(![self.managedObjectContext save:&error])
        {
            NSLog(@"whoops, couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        }
    }
```

and fetching data this way

```
managedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext;
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription
                                   entityForName:@"Chatuser" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [request setEntity:entity];
    NSError *error;

    NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"chatuser == %@", appDelegate.chatUser];
    [request setPredicate:pred];

    NSArray *userinfo = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

    if([userinfo count]>0)
    {

        Chatuser *user = [userinfo objectAtIndex:0];
        NSSet *messageset = user.allchatmessages;
        self.messageinfo = [messageset allObjects];
        int message_count=[self.messageinfo count];
        NSLog(@"Message count : %d", message_count);
        for(int i=(message_count-1);i>=0;i--)
        {
            Chatmessage *chatmsgnew = [self.messageinfo objectAtIndex:i];
            [tableArray addObject:chatmsgnew.chatmessage];
        }
    }
```

now the problem is that chat messages is not coming in the order in which i am storing them. Like i am storing messages 1,2,3,4. and while fetching its coming like 2,1,4,3.....
I am not getting the problem. Can anybody suggest anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A fetch request does not necessarily return the objects in the order they were inserted into the database. If you need a specific order, you have to add an Integer attribute (e.g. `messageId`) to the entity, and add a sort descriptor to the fetch request:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sort = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"messageId"
         ascending:YES];
[request setSortDescriptors:@[sort]];
```

*Added:* The above method works if you fetch `Chatmessage` objects. So instead of fetching a `Chatuser` first, you could create a fetch request for the `Chatmessage` entity, with a predicate like

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"user.chatuser == %@", appDelegate.chatUser]
```

(assuming that "user" is the inverse relationship from *Chatmessage* to *Chatuser*), and the above sort descriptor.

Alternatively, if you have a `Chatuser` object, then you can sort `user.allchatmessages` like this:

```
NSSet *messageset = user.allchatmessages;
NSSortDescriptor *sort = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"messageId"
         ascending:YES];
self.messageinfo = [[messageset allObjects] sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[sort]];
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. Okey, integer attribute is a good suggestion. I'll try that.

Comment: i have a doubt, i have two entities, which has one to many relationship. So i fetching chatuser, and i am getting chatmessage in chatuser object. so i am setting messageid attribute to chatmessage, will sorting work this way. The point is i am fetching chatuser, so this way sorting will work. Please let me know if you are not getting my concern.

Comment: thank you so much for your answer. I'll try this and let you know.

Comment: thanks buddy. It's working, you are great :). BTW just for the record, i have used alternate solution.